# Creating ideals of finitely presented algebras in MAGMA

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, magma-cas

I want to create (right, left, two-sided) ideals of a finitely-presented algebra in MAGMA. I know how to do this for a free algebra, and the magma handbook  [indicates](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/920) that it's possible to do this for finitely-presented algebras too. However, when I run the following code,

```
K := RationalField();
F<z> := FreeAlgebra(K,1);
A<z> := quo<F|z^3>;

I := ideal<F|z^2>;
```

I get the error `Runtime error in ideal< ... >: Rhs argument 1 is invalid for this constructor`. Is it actually possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are redefining $z$ to be the variable of $A$, and it is then no longer recognized as an element of $F$. Try this

```
K := RationalField();
F<x> := FreeAlgebra(K,1);
A<z> := quo<F|x^3>;

I := ideal<F|x^2>;
```

Now Magma knows that when you refer to $x$, you are talking about the variable of $F$ and when you talk about $z$, you are talking about the variable of $A$.